# Install specific apk

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, apk, crosswalk

I am doing an Ionic project. Also I have added Crosswalk. So when I run `ionic run android`, **android-debug.apk** is installing in my phone. But I need to install the Crosswalk app (means  **android-armv7-debug.apk**).

Is there any way to install this app by using the command `ionic run android` instead of copying this file?

Thanks

[image: Apk Folder]

Comment: Are all these files created/updated every time you run `ionic run`? Or only the `android-debug.apk`?

Comment: Every files should update.

Comment: That's strange... Can you add the Crosswalk settings from your `config.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible with an ionic comand.

But you can do this.

```
ionic build android
adb -d install /path/to/file/android-armv7-debug.apk
```